# Passing strings from screen to screen - Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Im currently having a problem that when going to the last screen where its supposed to keep all the variables from the screens behind all the values from the viewmodels turn null the instant it goes to the last screen.

How can i make so that it doesn't turn null and i can use it on the last screen.

The viewmodels used

```
class QrCreate1ViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var selectedBlock by mutableStateOf("")
    var selectedRoom by mutableStateOf("")
    var selectedMachine by mutableStateOf("")

    fun optionsSelected(block: String, room: String, machine: String) {
        selectedBlock = block
        selectedRoom = room
        selectedMachine = machine

    }
}

class QrCreate2ViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var name by mutableStateOf("")
    var processor by mutableStateOf("")
    var ram by mutableStateOf("")
    var powerSupply by mutableStateOf("")

    fun optionsWtritten(_name: String, _processor: String, _ram: String, _powerSupply: String) {
        name = _name
        processor = _processor
        ram = _ram
        powerSupply = _powerSupply
    }

}
```

The first screen to get the data

```
fun QrCreatePhase1(navController: NavController) {
    val viewModel = viewModel<QrCreate1ViewModel>()

    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val blocks = listOf("Bloco A", "Bloco B", "Bloco C", "Bloco D", "Bloco E")
    var selectedBlock by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    var textFiledSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
    val icon = if (expanded) {
        Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowUp
    } else {
        Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowDown
    }

    var expanded2 by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var rooms by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf<String>()) }
    var selectedRoom by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val icon2 = Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowDown

    var expanded3 by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val machines = listOf("Computador 1", "Computador 2", "Computador 3", "Computador 4", "Computador 5")
    var selectedMachine by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val icon3 = Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowDown

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 30.dp, topEnd = 30.dp))
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {

        ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
            expanded = expanded,
            onExpandedChange = {
                expanded = !expanded
            }
        ) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = selectedBlock,
                readOnly = true,
                onValueChange = { selectedBlock = it },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .menuAnchor()
                    .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                        textFiledSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
                    },
                label = { Text(text = "Escolha um bloco") },
                trailingIcon = {
                    Icon(icon, "", Modifier.clickable { expanded = !expanded })
                }
            )
            ExposedDropdownMenu(
                expanded = expanded,
                onDismissRequest = {
                    expanded = false
                }
            ) {
                blocks.forEach { block ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(
                        text = { Text(text = block) },
                        onClick = {
                            selectedBlock = block
                            rooms = listOf(
                                "Sala ${block.last()}0.03",
                                "Sala ${block.last()}0.04",
                                "Sala ${block.last()}0.05"
                            )
                            selectedRoom = ""
                            //expanded2 = true
                        },
                        contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding,
                    )
                }
            }

        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))

        if (selectedBlock.isNotEmpty()) {
            ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
                expanded = expanded2,
                onExpandedChange = {
                    expanded2 = !expanded2
                }
            ) {
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = selectedRoom,
                    readOnly = true,
                    onValueChange = { selectedRoom = it },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .menuAnchor()
                        .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                            textFiledSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
                        },
                    label = { Text(text = "Escolha uma sala") },
                    trailingIcon = {
                        Icon(icon2, "", Modifier.clickable { expanded2 = !expanded2 })
                    }
                )
                ExposedDropdownMenu(
                    expanded = expanded2,
                    onDismissRequest = {
                        expanded2 = false
                    }
                ) {
                    rooms.forEach { room ->
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            text = { Text(text = room) },
                            onClick = { selectedRoom = room },
                            contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding,
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))

        if(selectedRoom.isNotEmpty()){
            ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
                expanded = expanded3,
                onExpandedChange = {
                    expanded3 = !expanded3
                }
            ) {
                OutlinedTextField(
                    value = selectedMachine,
                    readOnly = true,
                    onValueChange = { selectedMachine = it },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .menuAnchor()
                        .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                            textFiledSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
                        },
                    label = { Text(text = "Escolha uma máquina") },
                    trailingIcon = {
                        Icon(icon3, "", Modifier.clickable { expanded3 = !expanded3 })
                    }
                )
                ExposedDropdownMenu(
                    expanded = expanded3,
                    onDismissRequest = {
                        expanded3 = false
                    }
                ) {
                    machines.forEach { machine ->
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            text = { Text(text = machine) },
                            onClick = { selectedMachine = machine },
                            contentPadding = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.ItemContentPadding,
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))

        if(selectedMachine.isNotEmpty()) {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(Create2.route)
                    viewModel.optionsSelected(selectedBlock, selectedRoom, selectedMachine)
                          },
                Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Text(text = "Continuar")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the second screen that gives the data

```
fun QrCreatePhase2(navController: NavController){
    val viewModel = viewModel<QrCreate2ViewModel>()

    var name by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var processor by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var ram by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var powerSupply by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .fillMaxHeight()
        .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 30.dp, topEnd = 30.dp))
        .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
        .background(Color.White)
) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = name,
        onValueChange = { name = it },
        label = { Text("Nome") },
        placeholder = { Text("Nome") },
        singleLine = true,
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.large,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
            imeAction = ImeAction.Next
        ),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onNext = { focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down) }),
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = processor,
        onValueChange = { processor = it },
        label = { Text("Processador") },
        placeholder = { Text("Processador") },
        singleLine = true,
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.large,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
            imeAction = ImeAction.Next
        ),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onNext = { focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down) }),
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = ram,
        onValueChange = { ram = it },
        label = { Text("RAM") },
        placeholder = { Text("RAM") },
        singleLine = true,
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.large,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
            imeAction = ImeAction.Next
        ),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onNext = { focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down) }),
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = powerSupply,
        onValueChange = { powerSupply = it },
        label = { Text("Fonte") },
        placeholder = { Text("Fonte") },
        singleLine = true,
        shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.large,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
            imeAction = ImeAction.Done
        ),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { focusManager.clearFocus() }),
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))

    if (name.isNotEmpty() && processor.isNotEmpty() && ram.isNotEmpty() && powerSupply.isNotEmpty()) {
        Button(
            onClick = {
                navController.navigate(Create3.route)
                viewModel.optionsWtritten(name, processor, ram, powerSupply)
                      },
            Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(text = "Continuar")
        }
    }
}

}
```

The final screen where its supposed to receive the data from the past screens

```
fun QrCreateFinal(navController: NavController){

    val viewModel1: QrCreate1ViewModel = viewModel()
    val viewModel2: QrCreate2ViewModel = viewModel()

    var qrName by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

    val selectedBlock = viewModel1.selectedBlock
    val selectedRoom = viewModel1.selectedRoom
    val selectedMachine = viewModel1.selectedMachine
    val name = viewModel2.name
    val processor = viewModel2.processor
    val ram = viewModel2.ram
    val powerSupply = viewModel2.powerSupply

    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 30.dp, topEnd = 30.dp))
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp)
            .background(Color.White)
    ){

        val query = "Block: $selectedBlock, " +
                "Room: $selectedRoom, " +
                "Machine: $selectedMachine," +
                "Name: $name, " +
                "Processor: $processor, " +
                "Ram: $ram, " +
                "Power Supply: $powerSupply"

        CreateQR(query)

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        OutlinedTextField(
            value = qrName,
            onValueChange = {
                qrName = it
            },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text, imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { focusManager.clearFocus() }),
            label = { Text(text = "Escreva o nome do ficheiro") },
            placeholder = { Text(text = "Nome") },
        )

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        Button(onClick = { downloadQR(query, qrName, context) },
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        ) {
            Text("Download QR Code")
        }
    }

}
```

I tried reading the viewmodel and data classes documents from google on the jetpack compose and watching some videos but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could create shared viewModel and pass it to all required screens so it stays active during navigation:

```
@Composable
fun NavGraph() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()

    val viewModel: QrCreateViewModel = viewModel()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "screen1") {
        composable("screen1") { Screen1Screen(navController, viewModel) }
        composable("screen2") { Screen2Screen(navController, viewModel) }
    }
}
```

Or instead of a share viewModel, you could use MutableState which keeps the state for all screens.

Another option would we storing the data somewhere (for example in a Room DB) and pass the reference as a navigation argument.
Check for more info: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args

Answer (score 0):

Create instances of your viewModels using a viewModel Facotry. Then pass those instances to your functions. In your final screen your instantiating new viewModels that will have no data.

```kotlin
lateinit var viewModel: HomeViewModel

val owner = LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current

                    owner?.let {
                        viewModel = viewModel(
                            it,
                            "HomeViewModel",
                            MainViewModelFactory()
                        )
                    }

class MainViewModelFactory :
    ViewModelProvider.Factory {
       override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return HomeViewModel() as T
    }
}
```

You can do this in your main activity. This is one way of doing it. I'm sure there are others but this should get you started.